# Out of range exception when running Vertica query after upgrading dll

Tags: c#, dll, ado.net, vertica

### Background

I have an application that connects to our Vertica cluster through ADO.NET64 dll. It worked fine until a recent upgrade to the [7.2.x version for Windows](https://my.vertica.com/vertica-client-drivers/).

The Vertica dll appears to be is trying to set numeric fields from my query to a C# decimal causing the error.

Here's what the portion of my select looks like (previously worked fine with Vertica dll version 7.1.x

```
case when sum(customers) = 0 then 0 else sum(orders) / sum(customers) end as 'customers per order'
```

### Workaround

Cast every calculated field as a float. I shouldn't have to do this right?

```
cast(case when sum(customers) = 0 then 0 else sum(orders) / sum(customers) end as float) as 'customers per order'
```

### Code

This throws the exception:

```
VerticaDataAdapter adapter = new VerticaDataAdapter();
//adapter.ReturnProviderSpecificTypes = true;
VerticaCommand query = new VerticaCommand();
query.CommandText = sql; //sql query set previously
query.Connection = connection; //connection opened previously

adapter.SelectCommand = query;

try
{
    adapter.Fill(vertica_datatable);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
          //Exception thrown here
}
```

### Exception

> base = {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>       at Vertica.Data.Internal.DataEngine.VerticaNumeric.getDecimalFromBinaryBytes()
>       at Vertica.Data.Internal.DataEngine.VerticaNumeric.CreateNativeValue(Boolean...
>       at Vertica.Data.Internal.DataEngine.VerticaNumeric.getDecimalFromBinaryBytes()
>       at Vertica.Data.Internal.DataEngine.VerticaNumeric.CreateNativeValue(Boolean isBinaryTransfer)
>       at Vertica.Data.Internal.DataEngine.VType.get_NativeValue()
>       at Vertica.Data.Internal.DataEngine.VDataConverter.DoConvertToDefaultType(Object srcData, TypeMetadata srcMetadata)
>       at Vertica.Data.Internal.DotNetDSI.DataEngine.DataConverter.ConvertToDefaultType(Object srcData, TypeMetadata srcMetadata)
>       at Vertica.Data.Internal.ADO.Net.SDataReader.ConvertDataForOutput(Object data, TypeMetadata metadata)
>       at Vertica.Data.Internal.ADO.Net.SDataReader.GetValue(Int32 ordinal, Boolean convertTypesForOutput)
>       at Vertica.Data.Internal.ADO.Net.SDataReader.get_Item(Int32 ordinal)
>       at Vertica.Data.Internal.ADO.Net.SDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)
>       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DataReaderContainer.CommonLanguageSubsetDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)
>       at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.LoadDataRow()
>       at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)
>       at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
>       at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
>       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
>       at Connection.Run_Query(String sql, Connection_Types connection_type) in c:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\VerticaService.cs:line 55

### Edit

I changed the `connection_string.BinaryTransfer` property to false and am still getting some odd behavior. Here's what the results of my fields look like when set to false:

[image]

It's still the same when I set the `BinaryTransfer` property to true:
[image]

These are the actual values that should be displaying. I'm able to get the correct values by using `cast(LOWER_LIMIT as float) AS 'lower_limit'`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There were important changes in to the ADO.NET driver in Vertica 7.2 to increase performances. More specifically - as you can see [here](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/PDF/HP_Vertica_7.2.x_New_Features.pdf) -  "...*you can now use **binary transfer** instead of string transfer*...".

This new setting - as you can check in the [Connecting to Vertica Manual](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToHPVertica/ClientADO/ADO.NETConnectionProperties.htm%3FTocPath%3DConnecting%2520to%2520Vertica%7CClient%2520Libraries%7CProgramming%2520ADO.NET%2520Applications%7CConnecting%2520to%2520the%2520Database%7C_____3) is named `BinaryTransfer` and default value is TRUE. This is the parameter description:

> Provides a Boolean value that, when set to true, uses binary transfer instead of string transfer. When set to false, the ADO.NET connection uses string transfer. Binary transfer provides faster performance in reading data from a server to an ADO.NET client. Binary transfer also requires less bandwidth than string transfer, although it sometimes uses more when transferring a large number of small values.

You can switch back to the previous (pre-7.2) data transfer mode by setting this parameter to FALSE.

Comment: are there any other properties I need to worry about to get to the pre 7.2 behavior? See my edit. Thanks.

Comment: @flowbee In the 7.2 doc changes I don't see other changes that could affect your application. I'd contact Vertica Support.